# Is it possible to use Testcontainers on Spring (non Boot)?

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing, testcontainers

I am designing integration tests on kinda legacy app and I am facing the problem I have a services I´d like to use only for one run of Integration tests.

The app contains a multiple modules, 4 spring (non boot) applications and these are using these services:

- PostgreSQL database
- RabiitMQ instance
- ElasticSearch instance

Whole stack is currently dockerized via docker-compose (so using docker-compose up the whole app starts, database schemas are created etc).

I would like to achieve this via testcontainers. So start PostgreSQL container where I run flyway scripts to create schema and full database with data required to run (other data will be added in separate tests), then start RabbitMQ and then ElasticSearch instance.

All these automatically every time integration test run.

Is this even possible using "legacy" Spring (non Boot)?
And is this possible to automatize process that it could run many times on one server (so there wont be any port collisions). The goal is to run this on sobe Git repository after merge request was submitted to check if all integration tests pass.

Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 0):

Testcontainers is absolutely independent from Spring from the beginning, actually as I know some king of integration with Spring Boot has only recently been added.

There are a few ways to achieve that, the simplest would be to create a few containers as test class fields as described [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5) [1]

Yes, it is possible to achieve that without collisions, read [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/#exposing-container-ports-to-the-host). In short - Testcontainers exposes container's port (for ex 5432 for Postgres) on a random host port in order to avoid collisions, you can get the actual port as described in the article. For JDBC containers it can be even [easier](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#database-container-objects).

I haven't personally worked with RabbitMQ and ElasticSearch but there are modules for that, you can read about that in docs.

P.S. It's also possible to use Docker Compose support for that, but I can't find any reason why, just FYI, the approach above is simpler.

[1] `@Testcontainers` annotation will start them for you but you can also [manually](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#manually-startingstopping-containers) manage container lifecycle.